# Connect two content types via taxonomy

Tags: views

Currently I have a view called authors_under_book. When I enter the ID of a book, the view should show me the author's properties.

I have asked on [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1800646), but I didn't get any solution.

How can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: I have been battling with how to connect two content types using taxonomy for several days now, and have just got it to work. I have documented what I did over on the [question I asked about this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74821/create-a-view-which-shows-related-staff-members-based-on-taxonomy/75004#75004). I hope that this can help you too.